# Ruby 1.9.2 Character Encoding: invalid multibyte character: /?/

Tags: ruby, encoding

I'm trying to understand why this snippet of code does not work in Ruby 1.9.2 I'm also trying to figure out how it should be changed to be made to work. Here is the snippet:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :009 > str = "hello world!"
 => "hello world!" 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :010 > str.gsub("\223","")
RegexpError: invalid multibyte character: /?/
    from (irb):10:in `gsub'
```

Comment: What do you expect your "\223" character to be?

Comment: I think \223 is a left double quote and \224 is a right one. I'm not familiar enough with encoding to tell you much more than that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your ruby is in UTF-8 mode but `"\223"` is not a valid UTF-8 string. When you're in UTF-8, any byte with the eighth bit set means that you're within a multi-byte character and you need to keep reading more bytes to get the full character; that means that `"\223"` is just *part* of a UTF-8 encoded character, hence your error.

0223 and 0224 (147 and 148 decimal) are "smart" quotes in the [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) character set but Windows-1252 isn't UTF-8. In UTF-8 you want `"\u201c"` and `"\u201d"` for the quotes:

```
>> puts "\u201c"
“
>> puts "\u201d"
”
```

So if you're trying to strip out the quotes then you probably want one of these:

```
str.gsub("\u201c", "").gsub("\u201d", "")
str.gsub(/[\u201c\u201d]/, '')
```

Comment: how did you know `0223` is `"\u201c"` ?

Comment: Can you tell me the unicode equivalent of `'ô'` ? I need it.. please

Comment: I actually didn't find in this [*table*](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) the 2 `"\u201d"` and `"\u201c"` .. Please help me.

Comment: @Arup: Experience has told me that these sorts of encoding problems are usually someone treating Latin-1 or Windows-1252 as UTF-8 so I looked at the Latin-1 and Windows-1252 character tables to see what was at `0223`, [Latin-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1) doesn't have anything at `0x93` but [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) does. Then you just need to backtrack to the Unicode version. You need to look at the [General Punctuation](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192) page.

Comment: Yes, that [page](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) I were, but I didn't find `"\u201d"` and `"\u201c"` there ... How did you search it there ?

Comment: @Arup: Look at the "go to other block" dropdown, it includes the hex ranges, 0x201c and 0x201d fall between 0x2000 and 0x206F so you want the "General Punctuation" section: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192

Comment: +1..Actually I am just learning from you, how to use that table.. Please don't mind. Now when you had `“` only, how did you search that table?

Comment: Probably with something like `"\223".force_encoding('windows-1252').encode('utf-8')[0].ord.to_s(16)` in irb to get the hex value. Then once you have the Unicode hex value it is easy.

Comment: Ohh! Great! Do we really need `[0]`? I think `"\223".force_encoding('windows-1252').encode('utf-8').ord.to_s(16)` enough right? and Why `hexa` convestion.. I mean when I will be having problem such, How should I know, if I need to `hex` conversation or not ?

Comment: You don't need the `[0]` but I like to be clear that I really do mean the first character; I use a lot of different languages so I have habits to help me avoid confusion. Most character tables are in hex because the `\u` convention uses hex (and that uses hex because all the character tables are in hex). Hex is more convenient than decimal when dealing with bytes and octal is too old school for most people.